# How to setup SSL connection (two way authentication) to MySQL in grails?

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, grails, groovy

I have setup MySQL server to use SSL by adding the server and client certificates and keys in **my.cnf** file. I have added the certificates in keystore and truststore for java. I have also modified the jdbc connection url by adding - "**verifyServerCerticate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true**" connection properties. The thing which I am stuck on is where shall I set the system wide properties for **keystore** and **truststore** in grails application. I have tried these lines of code

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/home/rjain/keystore")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/home/rjain/truststore")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password")
```

in Bootstrap.groovy file but to no avail I get the following error while starting my application -

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

Which file should I add the setProperty function calls or am I missing something else here?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after adding the above lines of code in config.groovy (grails 2)